# Getting exception information of sub process

Tags: python, winapi, process, error-handling

I want to make a simple windows executable loading program
which simply implemented using os.system('./calc.exe') in python
or WinExec(...), CreateProcess(...) in Windows API...

This would be a VERY simple and easy task.
However, I want to receive the detailed error report if my child process crashes.

I know I can get the error number code as the return value of
functions such as Popen.call() in Python, or something...

But when windows binary crashes, I can see the detailed error report
which contains the name of crashed module, violation code(0xC0000005, etc)
offset of crashed module, time, etc...

How can I get these information from the parent process and what would be the most easy and simple way to implement this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but something like this should do the trick:

```
import logging
import subprocess

cmd = "ls -al /directory/that/does/not/exist"  # <- or Windows equivalent
logging.info(cmd)
try:
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
except OSError, err:
    logging.error(err.child_traceback)
(stdout, stderr) = process.communicate()
logging.debug(stdout)
if not stderr is None:
    logging.error(stderr)
```

Comment: Thank you but it does not give me what I want, it just prints ERROR:root:... What I want to get is Windows Error Reporting results of crashed child process..